# How to get the files list from a subsite of Microsoft sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently using the below api to get the drives under the "Teams Site" in sharepoint.

```
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives".
```

My requirement is how to fetch the drives listed in sites(including sub sites) other than team site.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume you want to list the drives in the site.

First, we can use the `/sites/root` or `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists` to get the id property of the other site.

Then we can use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives` to retrieve the drives of the sites.

Comment: This fetch drives from Team Site only. my requirement is to fetch content from the subsite of {site-id}.

Comment: My apologize, we can use the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/sites` to get the id of the subsite, then we use the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives` endpoint to retrieve the drives